# Añadir scroll view vertical a una tabla HTML

Tags: html, scroll, html-tabla

tengo una tabla en HTML con 13 columnas de las cuales necesito agregar un scroll vertical y que los cabezales se queden fijo, he visto varias guías pero al final lo que hacen es dañar mis columnas y desordenando las.

Pueden usar esta tabla como ejemplo : https://jsfiddle.net/bumsg4x8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una tabla no puede desplazarse. Necesitas hacer algunos trucos para obtener un cuerpo de desplazamiento. Por ejemplo; un div envolvente con desplazamiento y un encabezado de tabla de posición absoluta o fija.

Yo te puedo ayudar con eso, pero debes aceptar que con tablas no se puede.

**Update**

Haré un ejemplo rápido:

```css
        body {margin:0;}
        
        .navbar {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          
        }
        
        .navbar a {
          float: left;
          display: block;
          color: #f2f2f2;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
          width: 30%;
        }
        
        .navbar a:hover {
          background: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
        
        .main {
            padding: 16px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            height: 1500px;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }

        .col {
            width: 30%;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
   <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="main">
            <div class="col-1 col">
                <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
                <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
                <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col">
                <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
                <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
                <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>
            

            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col">
                <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
                <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
                <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>
            

            </div>
      </div>
```

Lo más cercano a lo que pides es esto, me faltó agregarle los bordes, pero es tan simple como agregarle border: solid #000 1px; por ejemplo, al código de más arriba.

Comment: Sería genial que agregaras un ejemplo de lo que expones a tu respuesta

Comment: Saludos reynal gracias por la respuesta, pero de igual forma seria bueno que hagas un ejemplo no solo para mi sino para cualquier otro programador que se vea en la misma